# Define a macro to replace code

Tags: ios, objective-c, macros, c-preprocessor, testflight

I'm using TestFlight and I've got this macro to replace NSLog the the TestFlight remote logging equivalent.

```
 #define NSLog(__FORMAT__, ...) TFLog((@"%s [Line %d] " __FORMAT__), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

I have just copy pasted this from the TestFlight website and now I'd like to create my own for a slightly different purpose.

I'd like to be able to type...

```
MyEventLog(@"Something happened.");
```

...and for it to interpret it as...

```
[[MyEventLogManager sharedInstance] newLogWithText:@"Something happened"];
```

I'm just not sure how the syntax works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#define MyEventLog(message) [[MyEventLogManager sharedInstance] newLogWithText:message]
```

However you will find it useful to provide a varargs-version of that method, so you can pass it formatted text:

```
- (void)newLogWithFormat:(NSString *)format, ...
{
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, format);
    NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:va];
    va_end(va);

    [self newLogWithText:message];

    // If not using ARC, then:
    // [message release];
}
```

and use:

```
#define MyEventFormat(__FORMAT__, ...) [[MyEventLogManager sharedInstance] newLogWithFormat:__FORMAT__, ##__VA_ARGS__]
```

Comment: Do I have to write my function to interpret the formatting? Or is the NSString format the full string? Thanks again

Comment: @Fogmeister I have updated my answer showing the implementation of the logging method, rather than its declaration.  I also changed the name of the macro to `MyEventFormat` so you could use both the single-string and varargs versions.

Comment: @Fogmeister Don't forget to release that message if you aren't using ARC!

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at my LoggingEngine, I use something similar to this.

```
#define PBLog(s,...) [PBLog logFile:__FILE__ withLineNumber:__LINE__ andFormat:(s), ##__VA_ARGS__]
```

Here you can see that I call the method `[PBLog logfile:withLineNumber:andFormat:]`

https://github.com/nerdishbynature/PBLog